# Is the name of the target method available in a before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to make the name of target method available in a before filter.

For example, I have the following code

```
before_filter :login

def show
   #...
end

def login
   # ...
   # get the name of method original called 
   # ...
end
```

`http://<host>/show` is called, which subsequently calls login

Can I get a `show` string or something similar so a I can pass an instruction to the login which actually takes place on a different controller to return to the original target method

Comment: I am just trying it now, is param parameter available to before_filter and is the action the target method?

Comment: well: there are two yeses here

Comment: @apneadiving make your comment into an answer and I will up-mark it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply get the action from the params: `params[:action]`

Answer (score 1):

As @apneadiving mentioned, you can access `params[:action]` to get the "target" (i.e "show", "index", etc).

One word of caution is that generally for before_filters you should use `request.params` instead of just `params` because sometimes using just `params` can cause odd behaviour (I've done this in the past. I don't remember the exact odd behaviour, but it was not ideal). Also, if you are updating the params, I find I need to merge in to request.params instead of just doing something like `params[:key] = value`.

Comment: updating params is bad practice. You should never do that.

Comment: Actually I think it's fine. You may need to sanitize them, or maybe you're prepping the params for some other action.